# to read a file in UNIX and manipulate

Tags: unix, awk

I have one requirement that i have to read the file and manipulate. I have to replace the single double quote into double double quote if it is found in any fields. fields are separated by |.
Please find below for better understanding.

Input:

```
1234567|9393874|"Hi"|"How are "you""
98647489|20370483|"i am "good""|"what about "you""
```

output :

```
1234567|9393874|"Hi"|"How are ""you"""
98647489|20370483|"i am ""good"""|"what about ""you"""
```

Comment: Have you looked at `man sed`?

Comment: i am new in UNIX so you have some idea please help. i will look into sed. thanks.

Comment: Can `|` appear inside the quoted fields, e.g. `1234567|9393874|"Hi"|"We use a pipe (|) as separator"`?

Comment: yes pipe can appear in the field.

Comment: How can we tell a pipe inside a field from a pipe as used as a field separator? If we replace `good` with `|` in your second example it becomes `98647489|20370483|"i am "|""|"what about "you""` so how would you write an algorithm such that the `|` that replaced `good` is recognized as being inside field `"i am "|""` rather than a field separator between a field `"i am "` and a field `""`?

Comment: Tackle the problem at the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would replace all the "edge" quotes with another character and then replace the "inner" ones:

```
sed -e 's/|"/|_/g' -e 's/"|/_|/g' -e 's/"$/_/' file | sed 's/"/""/g' | sed 's/_/"/g'
```

It returns:

```
1234567|9393874|"Hi"|"How are ""you"""
98647489|20370483|"i am ""good"""|"what about ""you"""
```

Step by step:

```
$ sed -e 's/|"/|_/g' -e 's/"|/_|/g' -e 's/"$/_/' a 
1234567|9393874|_Hi_|_How are "you"_
98647489|20370483|_i am "good"_|_what about "you"_
$ sed -e 's/|"/|_/g' -e 's/"|/_|/g' -e 's/"$/_/' a | sed 's/"/""/g' 
1234567|9393874|_Hi_|_How are ""you""_
98647489|20370483|_i am ""good""_|_what about ""you""_
$ sed -e 's/|"/|_/g' -e 's/"|/_|/g' -e 's/"$/_/' a | sed 's/"/""/g' | sed 's/_/"/g'
1234567|9393874|"Hi"|"How are ""you"""
98647489|20370483|"i am ""good"""|"what about ""you"""
```

Comment: thanks for your answer.actually, i have the data file with more than 1 crore of records. will it be feasible in this case ?

Comment: @user1891602 give representative input and feedback about if this approach helped.

Comment: @user1891602 so did this approach help you? If so, you can mark as accepted by clicking on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.